# Play video with contrast, brightness, rotation and flip on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, video

i have mp4 video. And i need to play it in my iPad application in custom view.

Also i need next options:

- Playback control (pause, play, stop)
- Speed control (0.5x, 1x, 2x ...)
- Contrast/brightness/sharpness
- Flip
  and rotation

Optionally:

- video frame navigation

What is the best way to implement it?
MB, split video to frame pictures (i can do this on server side) and emulate video via UIImageView or GLImageProcessing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution, i use is split video to frames on server side and animate it on client side via OpenGLES.

I can apply filters to images, control play speed, navigate etc.